# Radon-Nikodym derivative of pushforward of Lebesgue measure by differentiable function with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure, jacobian, geometric-measure-theory

Here is the set up:

- $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a **measurable** function
- $\lambda^n$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure
- $f_*\lambda^n$ is the pushforward of $\lambda^n$ by $f$
- $f_*\lambda^n \ll \lambda^m$

> What do we know about the Radon-Nikodym derivative
> $$
> \frac{d f_*\lambda^n}{d\lambda^m}
> $$
> for different types of $f$?

Notice this Radon-Nikodym derivative exists as long as $f_*\lambda^n$ and $\lambda^m$ are sigma-finite measures **on the same space**, which is true in this setup.

#### Examples

For instance, using the [Change of Variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula) and [Integration by Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) when $f$ is a **diffeomorphism**, the Radon-Nikodym derivative is the absolute determinant Jacobian (see Billingsley "Probability and Measure", Theorem 17.2)
$$
\frac{d f_*\lambda^n}{d\lambda^m} = |\det J_f|.
$$
I have an intuition, based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411706/relationship-between-disintegration-theorem-and-co-area-formula) question, (but I have never seen it proven or mentioned anywhere) that when $f$ is simply **differentiable**, then the Radon-Nikodym derivative is the multidimensional Jacobian defined in Federer's "Geometric Integration Theorem" (Lemma 5.1.4)
$$
\frac{d f_*\lambda^n}{d\lambda^m} = \begin{cases}
    \mathcal{J}_n f(x) = |\det J_f(x)| && \text{ if } n = m \\
    \mathcal{J}_n f(x) = \sqrt{\det J_f(x)^\top J_f(x)} && \text{ if } n \leq m \\
    \mathcal{J}_m f(x) = \sqrt{\det J_f(x) J_f(x)^\top} && \text{ if } n \geq m
\end{cases}
$$
However I have no idea how to go about proving this.

Comment: If you lose smoothness, usually integration helps

Comment: @Ilya I'm not sure what you mean sorry..

Comment: Ah, I've missed the point that you don't drop smoothness, you have difference in dimensions. That nevermind my previous comment.

Comment: @Ilya do you have any idea if the statement I make for $f$ differentiable is true? And where I could find a reference to it?

Comment: I'd expect some GMT books, like Federer's. Not my field, I was a bit more into general MT.

Comment: Note that the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{df_* \lambda^n}{d\lambda^m}$ only exists if $f_* \lambda^n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda^m$. So for example if $f$ is constant the derivative will not exist.

Comment: @bs_math good point, I forgot about that. I will add it to the assumptions

Comment: @Ilya I expected it too but I checked Federer's, Billingsley and more books but found nothing.. perhaps it has another name

Comment: Look at the area and coarea formulas in the measure theory book by Evans and Gariepy.

Comment: Note that when $f$ is a diffeomorphism it must be that $n = m$.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition makes no sense - the Jacobian is at a point of the domain, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative is at a point in the target.

```
Notice this Radon-Nikodym derivative exists [...] in this setup.
```

Not really. As was pointed out, the constant map pushes forward to an "infinite-sized delta" at the value. This has no Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to Lebesgue, both because the pushforward is not sigma-finite (hence "infinite-sized") and because it is not absolutely continuous relative to Lebesgue (hence "delta").

A simple case with a decent answer is when $f$ is a proper submersion. Then at $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ we have $M=f^{-1}(y)$ a smooth compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the derivative $\frac{d f_*\lambda^n}{d\lambda^m}(y)$ is the integral over $M$ of the multidimensional Jacobian you mention (note that this reduces to the correct answer when $f$ is a diffeo). The reason is that the multidimensional Jacobian is the infinitesimal volume stretching factor between tangent spaces on domain and target. In other words, a preimage of a small neighborhood of $y$ of volume $V$ is a thickening of $M$, fibered over $M$ by orthocomplements to the kernel of $f$ at every $x\in M$. The volume of each such orthocomplement is approximately $V\times Jf(x)$, so that the overall volume of the thickening is approximately $V\times\int_M (Jf(x)) d(vol M)$. The Radon-Nikodym derivative is the limit of the ratio of that to $V$  when $V$ becomes small.

Comment: I will read your answer a few times to try and understand it better but you raise some good points. The main reason I thought my intuition would make sense is because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411706/relationship-between-disintegration-theorem-and-co-area-formula) question

Comment: Well, there are issues there too. Firstly, the disintegration theorem starts with a probability measure on the domain, i.e. one of total measure 1. This avoids some of the "properness" issues (i.e. the pushforward by a  constant map is then the unit-sized delta at the value). Secondly, all the RHSes have integrals over $\xi^{-1}$ aka over $f^{-1}$ in my answer. Thirdly, to go from measure-theoretic statements on integrals to a pointwise thing like R-N derivative, you need some regularity (which we have for submersions), otherwise you can get a.e. statements at best.

Answer (score 1):

If $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are open sets and $f: U \to V$ is a smooth injective map with non-vanishing Jacobian determinant $J_f$, then the pushforward $\lambda \circ f^{-1}$ (denoted $f_*\lambda$ in the original question) of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ (restricted to the $U$ and $V$, respectively) and it is given by:

$$
(\lambda \circ f^{-1})(\mathrm{d}y)
= \left[J_f(f^{-1}(y)) \right]^{-1} \lambda(\mathrm{d}y)
= J_{f^{-1}}(y) \lambda(\mathrm{d}y).
\tag{1}
$$

In other words, the term $J_{f^{-1}}(y)$ is the density of the pushforward measure $f_*\lambda$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$:

$$
\frac{(\lambda \circ f^{-1})(\mathrm{d}y)}{\lambda(\mathrm{d}y)} = J_{f^{-1}}(y).
\tag{2}
$$

More generally, if we have any measure $\mu(\mathrm{d}x) = h(x) \lambda(\mathrm{d}x)$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, then

$$
\frac{(\mu \circ f^{-1})(\mathrm{d}y)}{\lambda(\mathrm{d}y)} = h(f^{-1}(y)) J_{f^{-1}}(y).
\tag{3}
$$

This equation corresponds to the usual rule that a derived random variable $Y = f(X)$ for 1-1 function $f$ has density

$$
p_Y(y) = p_X(f^{-1}(y))J_{f^{-1}}(y).
$$

---

Theorem 17.2 of Billingsley states a related property; namely, if $f: U \to V$ is defined as above and $\phi: V \to R$ is a Borel function, then

$$
\int_{V} \phi(x) \lambda(\mathrm{d}x)
= \int_{U} \phi(f(x)) \underbrace{J_f(x)\lambda(\mathrm{d}x)}_{:=\ 
 \nu(\mathrm{d}x)}
\tag{4}
$$

All that is left now is to do pattern matching on the definition of the pushforward measure. Namely, with $\nu$ as defined above, consider the pushforward measure $(\nu \circ f^{-1})$; we have:

$$
\int_{V}\phi(x) (\nu \circ f^{-1})(\mathrm{d}x) = \int_{U}\phi(f(x))\nu(\mathrm{d}x)
\tag{*}
$$

Therefore, the pushforward of the measure $\nu(dx) = J_f(x) \lambda(\mathrm{d}x)$ through $f$ (denoted $\nu \circ f^{-1})$ is exactly the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.  This result is unsurprising, since applying $(3)$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(\nu \circ f^{-1})(\mathrm{d}y)}{\lambda(\mathrm{d}y)}
&= J_f(f^{-1}(y)) J_{f^{-1}}(y)\\
&= J_f(f^{-1}(y)) \left[J_f(f^{-1}(y)) \right]^{-1} \\
&= 1.
\end{align}
$$

---

It should be noted that $(*)$ is a very special property of the Lebesgue measure, and it is the essential equation that is needed to obtain equations $(1)$ through $(3)$, and not the other way round, which is why Billingsley states it as the key theorem.